# Why am I getting an error in my viewbox when I switch views?

Tags: wpf

I have a child view (user control) that has a button with a viewbox in it.  I am changing my view in the mainviewmodel by creating a datatemplate in my app.xaml and updating the viewmodel, like this:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:EditSettingsViewModel}">
   <views:EditSettingsView  DataContext="{Binding}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

and then binding my viewmodel:

```
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel, 
       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

Here is the code for my button:

```
    <Button Background="Transparent"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-5">
    <Viewbox Child="{StaticResource Save}" Height="40"></Viewbox>
    </Button>
```

When I switch my view it works but then if I switch it back to this view.  I get an error:  ''Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox.Child' threw an exception.' Line number '91' and line position '38'.'

If I cut and paste the whole canvas in there it seems to work. Thoughts?

Comment: The code needed for the switch is not mentioned in the question.
however, it seems that the problem lies with the StaticResource "Save". Try to verify that the "Save" resource is visible in the current view.

Comment: I changed my button and used a content control instead of a viewbox:    
         <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Save}"></ContentControl>                                                                                       This seemed to work